# How to change color of CheckBox when is not enabled?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using `CheckBox` and I want to change the color to gray of the `CheckBox` that are disabled with `IsEnabled = false` .

Is posible to change the color in XAML? If is not possible, how can I make it possible in code?

My XAML:

```html
            <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyles" TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Color" Value="{StaticResource checkBoxColor}" />
            </Style>
            
               <CheckBox
                                x:Name="FirstCB"
                                IsChecked="{Binding CheckedFirstCB, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyles}" />
                              
               <CheckBox
                                x:Name="SecondCB"
                                IsChecked="{Binding CheckedSecondCB, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyles}" />
```

Code:

```
FirstCB.IsEnabled = true;
SecondCB.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I don't know the differences between xamarin and wpf, but in wpf you would add `Style.Triggers` to your `Style` that can set the `Color` property depending on the `IsChecked` property. Something like [that](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/) if that's available in xamarin, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RenéVogt mentioned in his comment you can achieve that with a style [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers):

```
 <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyles" TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" Value="{StaticResource checkBoxColor}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger TargetType="CheckBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Color" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```